# Trouble with jQuery's JSON Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getweeklyartistchart&user=ElicitBelief&api_key=25135a535781328243f9e31968abc14&format=json', function(data) {
      alert(data)
    });
});
```

Firebug says: `GET http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getweeklyartistchart&user=ElicitBelief&api_key=25135a535781328243f9e31968abc14&format=json 200 OK
        144ms` and the URL is red, so it's presumebly not fetching the data at all.

I can't think what the problem is.

Comment: Is that the same domain as the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the url is in a different domain.  You'll need to use JSONP and add `&jsoncallback=?` to your query.  I assume that the audioscrobbler API supports this.

Answer (score 0):

Visiting that URL gives me a file that says, "Invalid API key - You must be granted a valid key by last.fm"

Answer (score 0):

According to that link http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/, you have to add an 
"&callback=?" at the end of your URL (reason for this, is that jQuery automaticly uses JSONP to bypass AJAX Cross Domain policy when using $.getJSON).

So, if you pass below url to getJSON: 
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getweeklyartistchart&user=ElicitBelief&api_key=25135a535781328243f9e31968abc14&format=json&callback=?
you'll get JSON respoonse with : "Invalid API key - You must be granted a valid key by last.fm"

Check this for demo: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/usoqu3/) (page is empty, but look at requests in Firebug console)